# Sum of attributes of a subset of the features

Tags: qgis

This is my attribute table of a line layer:

[image]

How can I get the length of all segments where `Rohr_1` equals `SNRVe 7x12x2` ?

Comment: Hallo Frank, hier werden normalerweise nur Fragen auf Englisch gestellt. Für Fragen auf deutsch kann ich dir die ["fossgis-talk" Mailingliste](https://lists.fossgis.de/mailman/listinfo/fossgis-talk-liste) empfehlen. Da wird dir bestimmt geholfen.

Answer (score 2):

You have different possibilities to achieve this. Two of them are:

1. Using expressions:

Create a new field with field calculator and use `sum()` function with `group_by` statement like this:

```
sum("Laenge_m", group_by:="Rohr_1")
```

2. Using virtual layers:

Create a virtual layer with a query like this:

```
select sum("Laenge_m") from yourlayername where Rohr_1 is 'SNRVe 7x12x2'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=dissolve#dissolve) your layer with the attribute `Rohr_1`. You will get a new layer where each `Rohr_1` entry is summarized. In your case all features where `Rohr_1` is `SNRVe 7x12x2` are comined in one row.
2. Make sure you use a metric coordinate reference system like UTM. This is important for the computation of the length.
3. Create a new field and compute the length using the expression `$length`